# Summing values in a Array of Tuples

Tags: scala

Using below code I'm trying to sum the Double values

```
val v: List[(String, Array[((String, String), Double)])] = List( ("a" , Array((("a" , "b") , 1.0) , (("a" , "c") , 2.0) , (("a" , "d") , 3.0) , (("b" , "c") , 1.0) , (("b" , "d") , 4.0) , (("c" , "d") , 3.0))) )

def sum(xs: Array[((String, String), Double)]): Double = {

  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def inner( xs:Array[((String, String), Double)] , accum: Double) : Double = {
    xs match {
      case x :: tail => inner(tail, accum + x._2)
      case Nil => accum
    }
  }
  inner(xs, 0)

}
```

But error :

```
Multiple markers at this line - constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type; found : 
 scala.collection.immutable.::[B] required: Array[((String, String), Double)] - not found: value tail - constructor 
 cannot be instantiated to expected type; found : scala.collection.immutable.::[B] required: Array[((String, String), 
 Double)] - not found: value x
```

is thrown.

Is my logic not correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`::` and `Nil` are list constructors so you can't use them to match arrays. It is possible to match on Arrays,although it is quite inefficient in this case since you need to keep constructing intermediate arrays between recursive calls:

```
def sum(xs: Array[((String, String), Double)]): Double = {

  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def inner( xs:Array[((String, String), Double)], accum: Double) : Double = {
    xs match {
      case Array(x, tail@_*) => inner(tail.toArray, accum + x._2)
      case Array() => accum
    }
  }
  inner(xs, 0)
}
```

Note a much simpler solution would be:

```
v.flatMap(_._2.map(_._2)).sum
```

You can use views to prevent the creation of unnecessary intermediate collections:

```
v.view.flatMap(_._2.view.map(_._2)).sum
```

Comment: is using v.flatMap(_._2.map(_._2)) also inefficient ?

Comment: @blue-sky - `map` and `flatMap` both construct intermediate collections they don't need, so you depending on the size of the input collections you could use views which should make it more efficient. I'd expect it to be more efficient than the first version though which does a lot of unnecessary work.

Comment: so in that case is iteration method I've added as an answer more efficient as its guaranteed to be O(N) ?

Comment: @blue-sky - The code you've posted only sums an inner array but a lazy `flatMap/map` solution should be linear in the number of inner array elements.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting the Array to List and using recursive pattern matching can use this iterative approach :

```
val v: List[(String, Array[((String, String), Double)])] = List( ("a" , Array((("a" , "b") , 1.0) , (("a" , "c") , 2.0) , (("a" , "d") , 3.0) , (("b" , "c") , 1.0) , (("b" , "d") , 4.0) , (("c" , "d") , 3.0))) )
                                                  //> v  : List[(String, Array[((String, String), Double)])] = List((a,Array(((a,b
                                                  //| ),1.0), ((a,c),2.0), ((a,d),3.0), ((b,c),1.0), ((b,d),4.0), ((c,d),3.0))))

def sum(xs: Array[((String, String), Double)]): Double = {

  var sum = 0.0
    for(x <- xs){
      sum = sum + x._2
    }

  sum
}                                                 //> sum: (xs: Array[((String, String), Double)])Double

sum(v(0)._2)
```